# error: code too large android studio

Tags: android

Al meter una modificación en la aplicación me ha saltado este error. Imagino que debo reducir código o algo así por lo que dice el error pero no se exactamente de que tipo, si son demasiadas variables o cálculos o que pasa. La verdad es que necesito todo el código y me ha dejado chafado cuando salto el error que nunca me había dado. 
Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Debes agregar el código que te produce el error. Jajajaj no, es una broma.  Mira http://stackoverflow.com/a/2407930/6658955

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un método no debe ser mayor de 64KB (65536 bytes), debes considerar modular el código que tengas dentro  y agregarlo a otros métodos que llamé tu método, no es común tengas un método tan grande!

Si alguién piensa usar esta solución, no se puede realizar con Android Studio :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407930/250260

Te recomiendo optimizar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Una fichero en bytescodes solo puede ocupar 64kb de memoria. Aunque hayas sobrepasado el límite no tienes porque prencindir de parte de tu código.

Seguramente se pueda organizar mejor, intenta separarlo en mas clases y funciones en diferentes ficheros y así no tendrás problema.

Si adjuntas tu código podríamos ayudarte a organizarlo mejor. Un saludo.

Comment: esta todo en un método y necesito que este así, ese es el problema

Comment: seguro que se puede desglosar el método en funciones más pequeñas o sacar parte de la funcionalidad a una clase auxiliar, si adjuntas el código tal vez podamos ayudarte a organizarlo, o si explicas por lo menos la funcionalidad en general